# Rename Pandas .agg() columns inside function call

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Is there a way to do the following **inside** the `.agg()` function?

```
hl = df[["sym", "bid", "ask"]].groupby("sym").agg(["min", "max"])
hl = hl.rename(columns={"min": "low", "max": "high"})
```

I see from the pandas [documentation](http:///https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) that you can use pd.namedAgg to apply different aggregations to different columns but all I would like to do is rename the columns in the original `.agg()` call.

I am used to writing in a very terse language (kdb+/q) hence wanted to reduce the number of lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```py
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

# Create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'sym': randint(1, 10), 'bid': randint(1, 10), 'ask': randint(1, 10)} for _ in range(10)
     ]).sort_values('sym').reset_index(drop=True)

hl = df[["sym", "bid", "ask"]].groupby("sym").agg([('low', "min"), ('high', "max")])
```

| Before agg. | After agg. |
| --- | --- |
| [image: input dataframe] | [image: output dataframe] |

Comment: Thanks! thats exactly what I was looking for but couldnt get the syntax correct. I was trying to use curly brackets like this {"min": "low", "max": "high"}